# LinkedList to Matrix (i guess) java

Tags: java, int

```
int test = recDada.getKey();
LinkedList<Integer> stack = new LinkedList<Integer>();
while(test > 0) {

    stack.push(test % 10);
    test = test/10;             
}
for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
    while(stack.size() < 5) stack.addFirst(0);
    System.out.println(stack.get(i));

        }
```

Here's the thing, I have this code which consists into a int getting my map key and it's a lot of numbers like that '73', '180' ... i need transform those numbers in something like this

Output i need:

```
0 0
0 0
0 1
7 8
3 0
```

Output i'm getting:

```
0 
0 
0
7
3
0 
0 
1
8
0
```

Can you guys give me a hint ? Thanks anyway, and sorry for my english :\

Comment: can you state more clearly what you are trying to achive? Select/fix a value of `test` and demonstrate output for it.

Comment: this piece of code goes inside a loop which gets all map keys and the map keys are some numbers like '73', '180' so the int test assumes those values. I need to catch those values and put just like the first output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use just one linked list then

```
LinkedList<Integer> stacks[] = new LinkedList<Integer>[recDataSize];
```

How to Input the data

```
for(int i=0;i<recDataSize;i++){
          int test = recDada.getKey();
          stacks[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
         while(test > 0) {
               stacks[i].push(test % 10);
               test = test/10;             
         } 
}
```

Therefore `stack[0]` will be `7,3` . `stack[1]` will be `1,8,0`

Printing function

```
//Add 0s to each stack
for (int i = 0; i <stacks.length; i++) {
     while(stacks[i].size() < 5) stacks[i].addFirst(0);
}

//Assuming all stacks are length 5 as they have been set in loop i
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
   for (int i = 0; i <stacks.length; i++) {
           System.out.print(stacks[i].get(j)+" ");
    }
   System.out.println();
}
```

Input needs be taken for every stack.

Another option would be to use an unused character like a -1 to separate the numbers in one long linked list. Then map that linked list to a 2d array and print:

Now for that linked list

```
LinkedList<integer> stack=new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

How to input:

```
for(int i=0;i<recDataSize;i++){
      int test = recData.getKey();
      stacks[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
      while(test > 0) {
           stacks[i].push(test % 10);
           test = test/10;             
     } 
     while(stacks[i].size() < 5) stacks[i].addFirst(0);
     //Add 0 in the input now not in printing function
 }
```

Therefore stack will be `0 0 0 7 3 0 0 1 8 0`

Mapping function

```
int map[][]=new int[recDataSize][5]; //This is the 2d array

for (int i = 0; i <recDataSize; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)  map[i][j]=stack.get((i*5)+j);
}
```

Matrix will be
    0 0
    0 0
    0 1 
    7 8
    3 0

Now just print with (i,j)

Comment: I'm trying to use this code but i'm getting a NullPointerException
for (int i = 0; i < stacks.length; i++) {
          while(stacks[i].size() < 5) stack.addFirst(0);      
    
   }

Comment: Sorry. Programming error meant stacks[i].addFirst Edited the code above

Comment: And where do I put this part while(test > 0) {

    stack.push(test % 10);
    test = test/10;             
}
?

Comment: Edited the answer hope this explains it more clearly. If you think the answer is correct tick it

Comment: May i ask you, if isn't too much, how do I map the linked list to a 2d array?

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
 System.out.println(stack.get(i));
```

to

```
 System.out.print(stack.get(i));

 if (i % 2 == 0) 
     System.out.print(" "); 
 else
     System.out.println();
```

Comment: This won't work. He doesn't want the odd ones to print on a new line. He has multiple numbers which he pushes into stack and wants to display them as a matrix.

Comment: @CarlSaldanha, I have suggested how he can print as a matrix, because I don't fully understand what he is trying to achieve without further clarification. If you understand completely, you are welcome to put your own answer next to mine.